# How to opt-in for AWS EC2 AMI from SDK?

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, amazon-ami, aws-marketplace

I am trying to launch an AWS EC2 instance using CentOS AMI [ami-21682673](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00A6KUVBW) from EC2 SDK. The AMI itself is a marketplace product and it requires an acceptance of the licensing terms.

The error I am getting:

```
In order to use this AWS Marketplace product 
you need to accept terms and subscribe. To do so please visit 
http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=eggbgx9svw4xhzs1omttdv29q
```

It is possible to accept terms from AWS web page. But I found no way to accept it from SDK. Any workarounds for this?

I know that the subscription will be saved in AWS once accepted. But my scenario is for a blank new profile with no subscriptions and SDK access only. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I had same error with an IAM user launching CentOS AMI via SDK. Once my root account went to the marketplace and accepted terms, all the IAM users were later able to SDK launch without the error. What do you mean by a "new profile"? A new aws account or a new IAM user?

Comment: @glenschler I mean a completely new account which never ever worked with CentOS. We wrote a Deploy4Me tool for cloud deployments and CentOS is not presented due to this limitation.

Comment: WTF is this prompt? Do you get it only once per AWS account? Or this would be required for starting every new instance?

Comment: @sorin once per AWS account for each AMI which requires EULA. Not sure how it works if AMI is updated for a new release of OS. I assume it will reappear for each unique AMI ID.

Comment: Thanks! If is once per AMI it would be ok. I was afraid that it would be each time I instantiate it.

Comment: @PavelKorsukov did you manage to solve this issue somehow? We're creating new AWS account on behalf of our customers with all corresponding infrastructure components automatically and can't pass this step. We want it to be automatic, but I have found no way to do it.

Comment: @ReVolly no, no solution for now. In our product we have decided to do not use marketplace AMI and focused on AMIs without EULA only.

Answer (score 3):

The terms and conditions for Marketplace published AMIs can only be accepted via the web site, and not via the command line or API directly. The EULA is required to be shown to the customer (in the case of the Debian AMIs in Marketplace, it is the Debian Social Contract which is displayed to the customer).

Comment: I already stated that this is the behavior we are trying to avoid. We are displaying EULA in our interface. So, this SDK behavior is a show stopper for us.

Comment: I bet that "da hua" is some kind of lawyer... from the category "computer says no!".

Answer (score 0):

this can be done via `terraform` now, using the Terraform AWS Provider [v4.58.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/v4.58.0/CHANGELOG.md)

see [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17146#issuecomment-1460285632) for more details

**OR**

via AWS SDK, example: [AcceptGrant](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/licensemanager/#LicenseManager.AcceptGrant)