# AWS OptInRequired and Terraform

Tags: terraform, openvpn

I'm trying to develop Terraform code for an OpenVPN Access Server, however I get the error:

```
aws_instance.openvpn_srv: Error launching source instance: OptInRequired: 
In order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept terms and 
subscribe.
```

Does Terraform have any support for using AMIs like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to opt-in for AWS EC2 AMI from SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504206/how-to-opt-in-for-aws-ec2-ami-from-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

We’ve found it easiest to accept the ULA one time through console and it solves that issue for the life of the ami.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, your account is not allowed to access the resource in aws, pls choose marketplace and that page will give your next instruction( setup credit card or else)

Oliver