# Accept End User License Agreement programmatically when launching an Image

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

When launching an EC2 instance from a marketplace image, you need to accept the End User License Agreement (EULA). This needs to be done only the first time the image is used to launch an instance. Any subsequent instantiations do not require this.

We have a web app which launches an instance in the customer's environment, but to be able to do this they need to accept EULA.

Regarding this I have the following questions:

1. Is there a programmatic way to get the agreement so that we could display it through our app and let the customer accept it. And then send the accepted agreement back to AWS? I came across this post: [How to opt-in for AWS EC2 AMI from SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504206/how-to-opt-in-for-aws-ec2-ami-from-sdk) but it is from 2015. I could not find if there is a way even today.
2. If there isn't a way to accomplish 1. we could tell the customer to go to the product page and accept it. But is there a way to confirm that they have done it? We thought of creating the instance as a dry-run to verify this. Dry run behaves as expected when the agreement has not been accepted; it shows the error message:

   In order to use this AWS Marketplace product you need to accept 
   terms and subscribe. To do so please visit 
   https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=9is83x7ec8xayzc533n58q6me 
   (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 401; Error Code: OptInRequired; 
   Request ID: ad180465-a1c4-47c0-8115-475b759bbbe6)

   But it shows the same error even when it has been accepted. I had to accept and deploy the image through the portal, and then the error went away.
   Is this how it is supposed to be? Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any other way to do this?

Any advice is appreciated.