# How to check that AWS EC2 AMI requires EULA Opt-In?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, ec2-ami

There is a question that asks [How to opt-in for AWS EC2 AMI from SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504206/how-to-opt-in-for-aws-ec2-ami-from-sdk). And as I understand, it's not possible to do it. But is it possible to at least understand if AMI requires Opt-In? And if our account already opted in or not? (via SDK, programmatically)

The problem I'm trying to solve is some application for end-user where the user provides their own credentials, and the application instantiates an instance of some AMI. Currently, if the user does not have EULA accepted yet, the operation will fail. And all we can do is pick the license link, ask the user to accept it and then retry what he did. This doesn't really seem to be user friendly though. So, I thought there might be a way to know that in advance. Is there any?